# How to pad zeroes for a number field?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-data-integrator

How can I pad an integer with zeros on the left (lpad) and padding a decimal after decimal separator with zeros on the right (rpad).

For example: If I have 5.95 I want to get 00005950 (without separator).

Comment: Is something like sprintf() available on your database? That would be the easiest and most readable way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the value up to thousandths but no more of the decimal part then you can multiply by 1000 and either `FLOOR` or use `TRUNC`. Like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( TRUNC( value * 1000 ), '00000009' )
FROM   table_name;
```

or:

```
SELECT LPAD( TRUNC( value * 1000 ), 8, '0' )
FROM   table_name;
```

Using `TO_CHAR` will only allow a set maximum number of digits based on the format mask (if the value goes over this size then it will display `#`s instead of numbers) but it will handle negative numbers (placing the minus sign before the leading zeros).

Using `LPAD` will allow any size of input but if the input is negative the minus sign will be in the middle of the string (after any leading zeros).

Comment: I prefer this one SELECT LPAD( TRUNC( 5.9516 * 1000 ), 8, 0 )
FROM   dual;

Comment: I had that in to start with then updated it and have now put it back with a little bit on the pros-and-cons of both versions when considering length-of-input and negative values.

Comment: The format mask will give a 9-character result; you'll have a leading space for positive values, which you could get rid of with the FM modifier; negative values will still be 9 characters though. Which may be fine of course. (And you've removed the bit about it always being 8 characters anyway!)

Comment: Nice maybe I will need something else for example if I have 5.9516 (the fourth digit > 5 so we increment the three digit by 1 . for example if I have 5.9516 I will get 00005952 instead of 00005951

Comment: @Abderrahim - just use `ROUND()` instead of  `TRUNC()`?

Answer (score 1):

How about multiplication and `lpad()`:

```
select lpad(col * 1000, 8, '0')
. . .
```

Comment: Yes you right but the problem if I have more than 3 digit after decimal separator for example 5.9562 I will get 5956.2

Answer (score 1):

`select lpad(rpad(replace('5.95','.',''),4,0),8,0) from dual;`

Assuming that either you have scale or not, `string` has to be suffix with `0` and prefix `0` till 8th digit. I am posting the query.

Let me know if this satisfies your requirement or anything else is required.

`select lpad(rpad(replace('5.95','.',''),4,0),8,0) from dual;`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select lpad(5.42562 * POWER(10, length(trim(regexp_replace(5.42562, '[^.]+\.(.*)$', '.\1')))-1), 8, '0') from dual;
```

where 5.42562 would be the column you want.

So basically, you are using Gordon Linoff's answer, but multiplying by 10 powered to the amount of decimals.

Comment: I only need to keep 3 digits after decimal separator

Comment: "and padding a decimal after decimal separator with zeros on the right (rpad)." dind't get that from your question :(. The I guess my approach doesn't suit you.